# Android Studio debugging on AWS Workspaces

Tags: android-studio, usb-debugging, amazon-workspaces

I am using AWS Workspaces to build an Android App. Everything works great and the speed with which I am able to work is just wonderful. However, one of the major issue I face is that I am unable to Debug my Apps via using USB debugging. 
Now I understand that use of AWS Amazon Workspace in such a scenario is bit unusual but I have to use Workspaces for some reason. 
Since Workspaces is a VM, so even the Android Emulator is not working.
Please let me know if any of you encountering similar problem and If you found some solution which can help to debug LIVE.

Comment: Have you tried to run application on Emulator (with HAXM)? What kind of emulator error you were getting?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to this? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Not yet!! Still struggling with this.!!

Comment: @AshootoshBhardwaj Need your help to solve `JAVA_HOME is not set and no java command could be found in your path` after installing Android studio in AWS Workspace (Windows). I can't edit environment variable as it requires admin credentials.